# Does $refs mess up interpolation?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm going through this vue.js course, author explicitly said that changing element's DOM via $refs won't impact interpolation, matter of fact, any change made directly to the DOM will be overwritten by interpolation, if any exists. That ain't happening.

Tried doing it via query selectors, instead of $refs, same result.

```
    <div id="app11">
        <h1 ref="myHeading">{{ val }}</h1>
        <button @click="viaRefs">Change value via $refs to 5</button>
    </div>
```

```
const vm11 = new Vue({
    el: "#app11",
    data: {
        val: 0
    },
    methods: {
        viaRefs: function() {

            this.$refs.myHeading.innerText = 5;
        }
    }
});

setInterval(() => {
    vm11.val++;
}, 1000);
```

I would expect text in this heading to display 5 for a moment after i hit button, then this setInterval changes val once again and Vue.js reacts by updating heading's inner HTML to val current value, as it did up to that moment. However, it gets stuck on value I gave it directly. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when you set the `innerText`, you're replacing the TextNode that Vue knows about with a new one. You've essentially lost your binding.

In your case, you can solve the issue by changing your assignment to:

```
this.$refs.myHeading.childNodes[0].data = 5;
```

With this change, clicking the button will cause your `<h1>` to temporarily display `5`, and then pick up where it left off.

If your intention is to "reset" the display value to `5` and start counting from there, then your assignment should deal with the `data` property directly, and not the innerHtml via `refs`:

```
this.val = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! So instead of replacing element's TextNode you changed the property of an existing one, at least I see it that way, and it makes sense.